# Middleware using Alice and HttpRouter

Tags: go, middleware, go-alice

I can't seem to work out how to use middleware and Http Router properly together.

My code is:

```
type appContext struct {
  db *mgo.Database
}

func main(){
  c := appContext{session.DB("db-name")}
  commonHandlers := alice.New(context.ClearHandler, basicAuthHandler)

  router := NewRouter()
  router.Post("/", commonHandlers.ThenFunc(c.final))

  http.ListenAndServe(":5000", router)
}
```

The **final** middleware is:

```
func (c *appContext) final(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  log.Println("Executing finalHandler")
  w.Write([]byte("TESTING"))
}
```

but I want my `basicAuthHandler` to be part of the **commonHandlers**. It also needs the `context` so that I can query the db.

I have tried this:

```
func (c *appContext) basicAuthHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  var app App
  err := c.db.C("apps").Find(bson.M{"id":"abcde"}).One(&app)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  //do something with the app
}
```

but I get the error **undefined: basicAuthHandler**. I understand why I'm getting the error but I don't know how to avoid it. How can I provide the `context` to the `basicAuthHandler` and still use it in the `commonHandlers` list for Alice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your middleware needs to have the signature

```
func(http.Handler) http.Handler
```

This way your middleware is wrapping handlers, not just providing a final handler. You need to accept an `http.Handler`, do whatever processing needs to be done, and call `ServeHTTP` on the next handler in the chain. Your basicAuthHandler example could look like this:

```
func (c *appContext) basicAuthHandler(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        var app App
        err := c.db.C("apps").Find(bson.M{"id": "abcde"}).One(&app)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)

    })
}
```

(though you don't want to `panic` in your app, and should provide a better error response)

Comment: Yeah I tried that but then I get: `cannot use c.basicAuthHandler (type func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)) as type alice.Constructor in argument to alice.New`

Comment: @tommyd456: sorry, I didn't look at what `alice` was, and thought your function signature was correct. `alice.New` takes an `alice.Contructor` as arguments

Comment: So is it not possible to do what I want to do?

Comment: Sure, you just need to create a function matching the signature of `type Constructor func(http.Handler) http.Handler`. You can use `http.HandlerFunc` to convert functions to handlers if you need (or you can use `http.Handlers` instead). You want your middleware to be wrapper of a handler, no a final handler itself. I'll come back and try to explain in an answer if I have time.

Comment: Appreciate your help but do the handlers on the first line need to be `http.Handler`?

Comment: The first line of the second code sample in your response that is.